# upgrade disrupted & nautilus crash

Tags: 14.04, networking, upgrade, 15.04

I was upgrading to 15.04 from the previous version. The upgrade was disrupted due to power problems.

After I booted the system, Nautilus is not working, network button not showing up. mouse not working but keyboard buttons work.

Is there a way to go back or forward now (internet not working though there is a connection)?

Comment: Do you still have the Ubuntu USB/DVD you installed it with?

Comment: No, I tried upgrade through internet connection

Comment: No, the original, old version DVD/USB - the one with which you *installed* Ubuntu (not upgraded).

Comment: Sorry I dont have it.

Comment: You can tell me what to do & I think i might be able to do it

Comment: Your best option is to download Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

run terminal window and execute as root or with sudo below command without quotes "apt-get -f install" or "dpkg-reconfigure -a". This usually solves problem with broken upgrade, and no, they will not eat your files :)

Comment: I cannot connect to the network, dpkg-reconfigure -a is not working (says unknown option. I did with sudo). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then go with this one (remove quotes):

"dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: Yes I did but no response.

Comment: Then it might be a little bit harder. You have two choices now. First, reconfigure nautilus package, with "dpkg-reconfigure nautilus" and then (it might not be installed) but try the same with package "libnautilus-extension1a". Reboot and check. Second option is to reinstall nautilus with "apt-get remove nautilus" and "apt-get install nautilus" and reboot.  It also might have happened that some other related packages were not fully reconfigured.  Oh, are you using wifi or ethernet cable for internet access ?

Comment: Since internet cannot be connected after the nautilus I installed again with the bootable pendrive. Thanks for the suggestions..